# Apache POI - Como colocar Hyperlink em uma imagem no Excel?

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Esse é o metodo que uso pra colocar imagens no Excel:

```
public void insertIcons(String URL, Sheet sheet, int colBegin, int colEnd, int rowBegin, int rowEnd) {
    try {
        InputStream iconInput = new FileInputStream(URL);
        byte[] byteTransf = IOUtils.toByteArray(iconInput);
        int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(byteTransf, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        iconInput.close();


        CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        Drawing drawingIcon = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchorIcon = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchorIcon.setCol1(colBegin);
        anchorIcon.setCol2(colEnd);
        anchorIcon.setRow1(rowBegin);
        anchorIcon.setRow2(rowEnd);

        Picture iconReady = drawingIcon.createPicture(anchorIcon, pictureIdx);
        iconReady.resize(1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Assim eu uso o metodo:

```
insertIcons(".idea/Icons/table.png", sheetName, 4, 4, 6, 9);
```

Seria possível colocar um Hyperlink nessa imagem para ir para uma outra Sheet na mesma planilha? Ou para um website?

Eu li que aparentemente a apache não oferece suporte para fazer isso, mas que teria como utilizando a lowerLevel API. Mas não consigui utiliza ela com sucesso

Alguma Seguestão?

Comment: Este é o stack em português. Traduza sua pergunta ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz a mesma pergunta em ingles e segue o link com a resposta!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141061/apache-poi-putting-hyperlink-in-images